# Gruntjs sass plugin

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm working in very big project and using GruntJS.
For compile sass files i'm using Gruntjs plugins SCSS and watch;

But it is very slow, for one run want 6-7 sec.

Comment: Sorry, but _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._.

Comment: If you are using ruby based sass to compile then I would recommend using [LibSass](http://sass-lang.com/libsass). It compiles a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

well the task is not slow, you need see how many files you are compiling.

e.g.: if you are compiling vendor css like boostrap font-awesome with you sass files of course will make that slow.

I suggest to you insert boostrap and fontawesome calls in your html and remove from your sass compiling

try use this task:
time-grunt

I hope that helped you somehow.